# Как раз'kinit'ится?

Tags: kerberos

Я с помощью kinit получаю ключ доступа идентификации, как мне его обнулить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утилита kdestroy уничтожает активные ticket авторизации пользователя Kerberos, перезаписывая и удаляя кэш авторизаций, который их содержит.

Если кэш авторизаций не указан, то кэш авторизаций по умолчанию уничтожается.

Удалить полученные билеты из кэша:

```
$ kdestroy
```